# How to code dart isolates

Tags: dart

So I started this port of my java chess engine and now I need to use and understand isolates.

My first try was very cumbersome.

A) I had to try and test the code outside of isolates since errors where not shown anywhere.

B) When I finally got the test to run I noticed that output from isolates are buffered and not written to the console in realtime.

Here's is my first test that now works but output is buffered and written after that the isolates are done ...

```dart
library chessbuddy;

import 'dart:isolate';

void main() {
//  slowPrime();
//  fastPrime();

  var port = new ReceivePort();

  spawnFunction(slowPrime, errorHandler);
  spawnFunction(fastPrime, errorHandler);
}

bool errorHandler(IsolateUnhandledException e) {
  print(e);
  return true;
}

void fastPrime() {
  int prime = 1;
  DateTime started = new DateTime.now();

  // -- Run for 10 seconds --
  int secs = secondsSince(started);
  int lastSecs = secs;
  while (secs <= 10) {
    if (secs != lastSecs) {
      print("$secs: Fast method reached prime $prime");
      lastSecs = secs;
    }
    prime = nextPrimeFast(prime);
    secs = secondsSince(started);
  }
}

void slowPrime() {
  int prime = 1;
  DateTime started = new DateTime.now();

  // -- Run for 10 seconds --
  int secs = secondsSince(started);
  int lastSecs = secs;
  while (secs <= 10) {
    if (secs != lastSecs) {
      print("$secs: Slow method reached prime $prime");
      lastSecs = secs;
    }
    prime = nextPrimeSlow(prime);
    secs = secondsSince(started);
  }
}

int secondsSince(DateTime since) {
  DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  return now.difference(since).inSeconds;
}


bool isPrimeSlow(int n) {
  for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

int nextPrimeSlow(int from) {
  while (!isPrimeSlow(++from));
  return from;
}

bool isPrimeFast(int n) {
  for (int i = 2; 2 * i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

int nextPrimeFast(int from) {
  while (!isPrimeFast(++from));
  return from;
}
```

Here is another test with a subprocess that receives commands and answers to them.
This one works and now I think I know how to do this.

Question! How do I check if an isolate is alive or not?
I couldn't find any method in SendPort.

```dart
library chesbuddy;

import 'dart:isolate';

void main() {
  try {
    port.receive((var message, SendPort replyTo) {
      print("Got answer: $message");
      // port.close();
    });

    SendPort subProcess = spawnFunction(process, errorHandler);
    subProcess.send(["echo", "svinhuvud"], port.toSendPort());
    subProcess.send(["think", "fenpos"], port.toSendPort());
    subProcess.send(["fib", 20], port.toSendPort());
    subProcess.send(["throw"], port.toSendPort());
    subProcess.send(["close"]);
    subProcess.send(["echo", "svinhuvud"], port.toSendPort());

  } catch (e) {
    print("Caugh an error: $e");
  }

}

process() {
  port.receive((var message, SendPort replyTo) {
    String command = message[0];
    print ("Got command: $command");

    if (command == "echo") {
      String txt = message[1];
      replyTo.send("echo: $txt");
      return;
    }

    if (command == "throw") {
      throw new StateError("APA GRIS KATT");
      return;
    }


    if (command == "fib") {
      int index = message[1];
      print("index = $index");
      int answer = fib(index);
      print("answer = $answer");
      replyTo.send("fib($index) = $answer");
      return;
    }

    if (command == "close") {
      port.close();
      return;
    }

    replyTo.send("Unknown command: $command");
  });
}

bool errorHandler(IsolateUnhandledException e) {
  print(e);
  return true;
}


int fib(i) {
  if (i < 2) 
    return i;
  else
    return fib(i-2) + fib(i-1);
}
```